# Qual é a origem da expressão "trinta e um"?

Tags: etimologia, expressões-idiomáticas

Em português (pelo menos no de Portugal) a expressão ***trinta e um*** significa ***problema ou confusão***:

> Mais vale fazeres como te disse, ou acabamos num **trinta e um**...

É uma expressão que ouço muitas vezes, mas cuja origem desconheço completamente.

[O Ciberdúvidas](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/a-origem-da-expressao-trinta-e-um/12379), bem como [o Dicionário da Porto Editora](http://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa-aao/trinta-e-um), sugerem que tem origem no nome dum jogo:

> **Trinta-e-um** significa: «embrulhada; zaragata; desordem». Deve ter origem num jogo de cartas. Nesse jogo, distribuem-se três cartas a cada jogador que pode pedir as que julgar necessárias para se aproximar dos trinta e um pontos. Se uma carta pedida ultrapassar os trinta e um pontos, o jogador sai de jogo.

No entanto — e para além do facto de o Ciberdúvidas dizer que “*deve ter origem*” — não conheço nenhum jogo de nome *trinta e um*. Conheço, no entanto, o [blackjack](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blackjack), que também é conhecido (mais um vez, em Portugal, noutros sítios onde se fale português não sei) como ***vinte e um***.

Existem algumas fontes que mostrem mais certeza no que diz respeito à origem da expressão?
É possível que haja alguma confusão no nome do jogo?

---

**Quick English version:**

The expression "**trinta e um**" ("thirty one") is used to mean **problem or confusion**, at least in European Portuguese.
The sources listed above mention that the expression *might have* its origins in an eponymous game. However, I don't know any games by that name, and the rules seem basically the same as those of blackjack — which is also known as "**vinte e um**" ("twenty one") in Portugal.

Are there any sources out there that show some more certainty about the origin of the expression?
Is it possible that there's some confusion regarding the name of the game?

Comment: O [Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/trinta%20e%20um) diz que no Brasil *bater o 31* significa *morrer*. Isto parece claramente relacionado com o jogo: ultrapassas o 31 e quinas.

Comment: Neste momento esta pergunta foi vista exatamente 31 vezes. É portanto a altura de esclarecer que o jogo do 31 vem referido em todos os dicionários. O dicionário do folclore brasileiro diz que há referências ao jogo em Espanha desde o séc. XVI. [O dicionário da Academia Española confirma a existência do jogo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=aYtGfNN).

Comment: Hmm, e aí especificam que o jogo pode ser de cartas ou bilhar...

Comment: Nos dicionários portugueses vem sempre, creio, que é de cartas. O dicionário do folclore brasileiro (Câmara Cascudo) só fala de cartas. Eu já joguei ao 31, mas foi com dardos!

Comment: Assim sendo, parece haver algum consenso em todas essas fontes; talvez tenhas material para uma resposta?

Comment: Eu posso escrever uma resposta com o que apurei, e com o que procurei e não achei. Vai é ficar só no campo da possibilidade: não encontrei nada que mostrasse claramente que a *arranjar um 31* vem do jogo.

Comment: É contigo, então ;) Eu de facto estava à procura de fontes conclusivas, mas se não as tens... :\

Comment: E eu que pensava que era do Liedson: http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_xjgWKl2bqJE/TKjH8SCWARI/AAAAAAAAAXA/SSzorbZreZs/s1600/Liedson_Armando_Fran_a.jpg LOL :D

Answer (score 8):

***Trinta e um*** no sentido relevante parece praticamente não ter deixado rasto escrito: os únicos exemplos relativamente antigos que consegui encontrar são no *Fado do 31* (1913), no *Fado do Ganga* (1916) e no *Fado do 17* (1936). Isto mostra que a expressão já era usada na segunda década do século XX. Anteriores a esta época, encontrei apenas dois *trinta e uns* que pudessem estar na origem da expressão: o jogo do trinta e um e a revolta republicana de 31 de Janeiro de 1891 no Porto.

Inclino-me a pensar que o 31 de Janeiro, se não originou a expressão, tenha pelo menos contribuído para modelar o significado que ela tem hoje. Mas vou apresentar os dados, e cada um tirará as suas conclusões. Em primeiro lugar note-se que esta parece ser uma expressão usada em Portugal mas não no Brasil. Ninguém se pronunciou ainda sobre isto, mas eu não encontro a expressão com este sentido nem no [Aulete](https://www.aulete.com.br/trinta%20e%20um) nem no [Michaelis](https://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno-portugues/busca/portugues-brasileiro/trinta%20e%20um/) nem no Houaiss.

### O Jogo do Trinta e Um

O ***jogo do trinta e um*** já era conhecido dos falantes de português no século XIX. Teve direito a verbete no dicionário de Cândido de Figueiredo de 1899 (Houaiss) e é referido em [O Ecco, Jornal Critico, Literario, e Politico de 22 de Dezembro de 1835](https://books.google.pt/books?id=R0MrAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA642&dq=%22trinta%20e%20um%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi-sP21j8jMAhWRzRoKHRRlDwAQ6AEIWjAJ#v=onepage&q=%22trinta%20e%20um%22&f=false) (gradia original e negritos meus em todas as citações):

> Alli se vião baralhos de cartas de todas as castas , honrados com os longos serviços e glorias adquiridas nos jogos do pilha , da bisca, do truque, e ***trinta e um***;

E há uma referência oblíqua em [“O Feiticeiro de Coimbra” publicado no *Universo Illustrado*, 1878:](https://docvirt.no-ip.com/docreader.net/DocReader.aspx?bib=RealGabObrasRaras&PagFis=35389&Pesq=)

> Regressando a Coimbra, com baixa pela junta militar […] era conhecido pelo *Trinta* […]
> Quando alguem passava perto d'elle, e lhe dizia: olha o *Trinta*, ou, adeus *Trinta*, respondia elle logo em seguida:
> ― ***Trinta e um***; ganhei.
> Era o unico cumprimento que dispensava fosse a quem fosse.

No jogo do trinta e um, quem fizer 31 pontos ganha, mas quem os ultrapassar perde. Compreende-se que este jogo tenha dado origem à expressão brasileira [*bater o trinta e um* (Aulete)](https://www.aulete.com.br/trinta%20e%20um), que significa “morrer”: basta interpretar *bater* como *ultrapassar*. Não se compreende tão bem como pudesse originar o significado de “zaragata, confusão”. Este [artigo no Ciberdúvidas](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/a-origem-da-expressao-trinta-e-um/12379) afirma que a expressão portuguesa tem origem no jogo, mas o único argumento que apresentam, que «os jogos, por vezes, são ruidosos, conflituosos e podem dar lugar a embrulhadas, zaragatas e desordens», não me parece muito convincente. Uma possibilidade seria a expressão ter origem no *jogo do trinta*, em que se perde ao ultrapassar trinta pontos. Este jogo é referido no [*Diccionario da Lingua Portugeza* de António de Morais da Silva de 1813](https://books.google.pt/books?id=GI8MAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA810&dq=ganha%20ou%20empata%20quem%20faz%20trinta&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi30OCk_NzMAhXLvhQKHRdlAFwQ6AEINTAE#v=onepage&q=ganha%20ou%20empata%20quem%20faz%20trinta&f=false) e no *Thesouro da Lingua Portugueza* do Frei Domingos Vieira de 1874 (Vol. 5, p. 822), que acrescenta que no seu tempo é *trinta e um* em vez de *trinta*:

> Jogo de cartas em que ganha ou empata quem faz trinta, ou fica em ponto mais proximo a elles que o contrario: hoje em logar de trinta é trinta e um.

### O 31 de Janeiro e Os Fados

O 31 de Janeiro de 1891 foi uma data marcante no final do século XIX e princípio do século XX, pois nesse dia estalou no Porto uma revolta de militares do exército em favor da abolição da monarquia e implantação da república. A revolta foi suprimida, tendo resultado em doze mortos e quarenta feridos. Com a implantação da república em 1910, os revoltosos do 31 de Janeiro foram considerados heróis, e muitas ruas ganharam o nome 31 de Janeiro, incluindo a antiga Rua de Santo António no Porto, que fora o palco principal da revolta.

Não é implausível que *trinta e um* adquirisse entretanto o significado de “zaragata e pancadaria”, que é o significado com que a expressão é usada no *Fado do 31, Fado do Ganga*, e *Fado do 17*.

O *Fado do 31* foi cantado pela primeira vez na revista *O 31* em Lisboa em 1913. O fado narra três cenas de zaragata e pancadaria, e tem como refrão «tudo bate em Portugal, o fado do trinta e um». Note-se que um dos significados de *fado* [(Aulete 3)](https://www.aulete.com.br/fado) é “destino, sina, sorte”. Podem [ouvir o *Fado do 31* aqui:](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EUa_kRHqGf8) e têm a [letra aqui](https://www.letras.mus.br/rodrigo/fado-do-31/).

O *Fado do Ganga* foi cantado pela primeira vez na revista *O Novo Mundo*em 1916, quando se discutia a entrada de Portugal na 1ª Guerra Mundial. Houve um versão gravada mais tarde, que podem [ouvir aqui](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8UllmV_X1U8), mas que omite a parte que nos interessa, que eu achei [aqui:](https://3.bp.blogspot.com/_NtVLnncC5dg/TTf1JdGUc2I/AAAAAAAABu0/6fhrIyb26TE/s1600/ip16ganga.jpg)

> Na guerra dos *alimões* / co’as nações / tem um exemplo de estalo.
> Pois, no fim d’esta embrulhada, / o que der mais *traulitada* / é que ha de cantar de galo.
> E quando chegar o dia / em que a gente fôr p’ra guerra… / (Ai! Ó! Sempre estás co’uma pressa!)
> Então, adeus ó Turquia. / A *Alimanha*, mais a Austria / Lá vão de ventas á terra.

> Vae-se a Verdum e pum! / Arma-se um grande ***trinta e um***,
> Vae-se a Berlim e pim! / Ha banzanada até ao fim.

O *Fado do 17*´, estreado na revista *Arre Burro* em 1936, é talvez o mais interessante. É precedido de uma declamação em que o agente policial nº 17 recorda os tempos de pancadaria da primeira república, antes do golpe de 28 de Maio de 1926, que iniciou o regime fascista. Na canção o polícia diz que esse tempo é dominado pelo fado do 31 (com várias referências claras ao fado de 1913), o qual teria morrido com a chegada do 28 (de Maio). Podem ouvir [declamação e fado aqui](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SZQVzRwG0l4) (minha transcrição; tenha dúvidas em relação a algumas palavras):

> [Declamação:]
> A polícia de outros tempos gravou na história da solha [*folha*?] as datas mais *mimoráveis* da chinfalhada e da trolha. Era a época das peras. Eram peras nos comícios a falar ao desafio. Eram peras à saída. Eram peras no Rossio. Que peras que a gente dava no lombo daquelas feras. Que peras que eu arreava. Isso é que eram tempos... e peras. Ai! meus filhos, que *sodades*. E em dias de grande gala, a gente todos de azul, tal e qual os *ginirais* de agulheta [?] e cordões; c’as luvas brancas calçadas, para não deixarmos marcadas as impressões digitais nas trombas dos matulões. E aquilo *inté* dava gosto. C’as fardas muito bem postas, ver a gente perfilada. O sol a bater na espada; a espada a bater nas costas; e as costas do cidadão a bater que nem pum… nas pedrinhas da calçada. Ai! meus filhos, que *sodades*

> [Canção:]
> O trinta e um é o fado / eterno e cantado / ai! como nenhum.
> Desde a Abissínia ao Japão / aquilo hoje é pão, / só há trinta e um
> Chegou à Rússia e à China / em Espanha domina / e chega a Irún
> Ai! meus filhos em Baiona / ai! que atafona, [?] / que trinta e um

> [Refrão x 2]
> Vai-se a Pequim, / trinta e um, há chinfrim, / vai-se a Ceilão / trinta e um, revolução,
> Vai-se a Nanquim, / trinta e um, há motim, / vai-se a Aragão, trinta e um, cachação.
> O trinta e um / hoje em dia é comum, / é tudo a dar, a cascar, a arrear!
> Ai, Portugal, é que é só conversar, / falazar, falazar…

> Em Portugal este fado / ergueu no passado / um hino ao zum-zum
> À porta da Brasileira / a tropa guerreira / era o trinta e um
> Depois veio o vinte e oito / e foi-se o biscoito / a bomba e o pum
> Ficou tudo sossegado / morreu o fado / do trinta e um

> [Refrão x 2]

Como o *vinte e oito* da canção se refere ao 28 de Maio de 1926, é tentador pensar que também *trinta e um* se refere a uma data, e o candidato óbvio é o 31 de Janeiro de 1891. Há ainda a intrigante expressão *31 da Armada*. Atualmente dá o nome a um [blogue monárquico](https://caoepulgas.blogspot.pt/2009/08/origem-das-expressoes.html). No blogue [cão com pulgas](https://caoepulgas.blogspot.pt/2009/08/origem-das-expressoes.html) diz-se que *31 da Armada* designa uma tentativa de golpe militar contra a Primeira República a bordo do cruzador Vasco da Gama a [19 de Julho de 1925](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revolta_de_19_de_Julho_de_1925), considerado como um ensaio do 28 de Maio. (O blogue também diz esta intentona está na origem da expressão *trinta e um*, o que não faz sentido, uma vez que a expressão já existia antes.) Ora como a intentona não tem nenhuma relação direta com o número 31, uma justificação para o nome seria que o *trinta e um* original foi o do Exército em 1891, e este seria o “trinta e um” da Armada. Ambas foram tentativas falhadas de mudar o regime da altura, mas em ambos os casos o regime acabou por mudar, 19 anos depois no caso do exército, um ano apenas no no caso da armada.

### Fechamento do Círculo?

É possível que o jogo e o 31 de Janeiro tenham ambos contribuído para a formação da expressão. Por exemplo, no jogo do trinta e um, quando um jogador ultrapassa os 31 pontos e perde, diz-se que *rebenta* [(Priberam)](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/trinta%20e%20um). Não é difícil imaginar o pessoal após a supressão da revolta do 31 de Janeiro começar a dizer que os revoltosos tinham rebentado o trinta e um. O [*Fado do 31* (excluindo o refrão) termina precisamente com estas palavras:](https://www.letras.mus.br/rodrigo/fado-do-31/)

> E depois está tudo torto
> E rebenta o trinta e um

Comment: De fato, sei que essa expressão não é de uso corrente no sudeste do Brasil e suspeito que também não seja no restante do Brasil.

Comment: @MarceloVentura Obrigado pela informação, finalmente alguém se pronunciou sobre o assunto. Isto é importante, porque se a expressão fosse comum no Brasil, seria pouco provável que tivesse origem no 31 de Janeiro do Porto.

Comment: Legal. Aqui no sul brasileiro quando as crianças jogam esconde-esconde elas "batem o 31" ou têm seu "31 batido" quando são achadas ou salvas no jogo.

Comment: @vnbrs, interessante. Imagino que isso venha do significado 'morrer' que *bater o trinta e um* tem no brasil segundo o [Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/trinta%20e%20um)?

Answer (score 1):

A associação à revolta de 31 de Janeiro de 1891, foi efectivamente feita no contexto de crítica política na 1a República e Estado Novo, o que não quer dizer que a origem da expressão não esteja no jogo do Trinta-e-Um. Com efeito, na letra do "Fado do 31", há uma passagem que pode intuir a relação directa com o jogo de cartas, algo como: "E agora vereis, vinte e quatro, vinte e seis, vinte e nove e trinta e um!". Esta contagem dá a ideia de alguém que está a tirar cartas até "rebentar". Em "História das cartas de jogar em Portugal e da Real Fábrica  de Cartas de Lisboa", Fernanda Frazão menciona o jogo do "Trinta" ou "Trinta-e-um": "jogo de cartas do séc. XV, no qual ganha ou empata quem faz trinta, ou fica em pontos mais próximo deles; a partir de certa altura, pelo menos a partir do séc. XVIII passou a ter a segunda designação."

Answer (score -4):

Mera suposição: estamos perante o número 13 invertido, número amplamente conotado com o azar e a má-sorte. Recordo que a própria palavra *invertido* tem também uma conotação pejorativa e menos positiva em certos contextos.

Comment: Esta resposta parece... numerologia. Praticamente todas as palavras podem «ter conotação pejorativa e menos positiva em certos contextos». E a palavra «invertido» não faz parte nem da expressão nem da sua definição.

Comment: @ANeves eu não disse que fazia parte da expressão, disse apenas que 31 é 13 invertido. Se acha que a Língua é uma ciência exata, continue a achar!

Comment: Pode ser que a tua resposta tenha sido tão mal recebida por acharem que ela devesse ser um comentário à pergunta ao invés de uma resposta em si.

Comment: Como disse, lamento, não faço análises histórico-filológicas. Se lhe perguntar porque o número 13 tem também um "significado" espero que não se canse na busca entre os dicionários.

Comment: Dizer que "a língua não é uma ciência exata" é um péssimo argumento. A Língua é um organismo vivo, mas o seu estudo (nomeadamente, nos âmbitos da história e etimologia, como é o caso) é uma ciência. Quanto ao "porquê de o número 13 ter significado"... já não nos temos de cansar em dicionários, existe uma coisa chamada Google, meu caro: https://www.history.com/news/whats-so-unlucky-about-the-number-13

Comment: @Rye ciência e ciência exacta são coisas muito diferentes